# Edit Custom Object via REST API in Salesforce

Tags: rest, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to edit a custom object I created in salesforce but I can't get it to work.  I am using this tutorial bellow and trying it using postman.  What am I doing wrong?

Login Tutorial:  https://rajvakati.com/2017/10/19/salesforce-username-and-password-oauth-flow/

Edit Tutorial:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm

My login request in Postman:

[image: Postman Login Request]

However when I try using the login token I got in my Edit request, I would get 401:

[image]

One potential issue is the edit request URL, the tutorial was not very clear on what to use and my instance is on lighting.  Is my URL correct?

```
https://<<INSTANCE_NAME>>.lightning.force.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/jorders__c/<<OBJECT_ID>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out using it the answer here, turn out the URL have to be whatever is returned from the login step.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099x7IAA